# How to redirect to my ip from ec2 instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS.

I have created an instance in AWS and it has some url (ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com) and I installed jdk, tomcat7 in this instance to run my java application.

This url was already shared with users to access. And I have a static IP which has 8GB RAM.

Now I want to redirect to my IP address while users hit the AWS url. Is this possible?

Can anyone assist me, I cant found solution for this in my searches.

Comment: If your IP is public then you can simply use a forward proxy installed at AWS instance (check out if they already have something like that) and forward all the traffic to your own IP.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "redirect to my IP address while users hit the AWS url"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking how to redirect your `ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com` address to a different IP address, then this is **not possible**. That DNS name always resolves to the IP address given in the name.

Correct practice is to create an **Elastic IP address**, assign it to an Amazon EC2 instance (so it always has the same IP address) and then create a DNS `A` record to point to that IP address. You can create the DNS record in whatever system controls your domain name (eg Amazon Route 53, GoDaddy).

Also, please note that your existing IP address might change if you stop and start your Amazon EC2 instance. This does not happen with an Elastic IP address.

Comment: Thanks Jhon, Yes I have an Elastic IP associated with this instance. I forgot to include this in my question, sorry.

Comment: Please note, I am looking to hit my IP when loading AWS instance url in browser.

Answer (score 0):

How many IP address or elastic network interfaces (ENIs) are attached to your instance? 
As @John Rotenstein has mentioned, you cannot redirect

> ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com

to your IP address (even it is EIP) since AWS does this for you by resolving the name to your IP address. From AWS docs,

> A public (external) DNS hostname takes the form
>   ec2-public-ipv4-address.compute-1.amazonaws.com for the us-east-1
>   region, and ec2-public-ipv4-address.region.amazonaws.com for other
>   regions. We resolve a public DNS hostname to the public IPv4 address
>   of the instance outside the network of the instance, and to the
>   private IPv4 address of the instance from within the network of the
>   instance.

Since the domain amazonaws.com is not in your control, you have to update your DNS record of your website (or if you don't have any, you may need to buy the domain name) so that your website points to your EC2 instance's IP.

Also, I'm lost at "And I have a static IP which has 8GB RAM", by static IP do you mean the EIP? In any case, IP address has nothing to with RAM size though :)

All the best!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, @sudo and thanks for helping answer @J Query's question. Just an FYI... If you have a question for the Original Poster (OP), you should ask it in a comment rather than in an Answer. It is best to avoid putting questions in an Answer, since they won't help other people who have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

You can still though achieve this by installing nginx and creating a re-write rule in nginx config as this:

(1) install nginx

```
yum install nginx
```

(2) Create an A record for your static IP to point to some dns like lets say new-name.com

(3) Add the following config to your nginx config and replace old-name.com and new-name.com with aws url and domain name created in step 2 above respectively

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.old-name.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.new-name.com$request_uri;
}
```

I hope that helps